# Firebase Error - Too many arguments provided to Query.startAt()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figurate why am I getting this error

> FirebaseError: Too many arguments provided to Query.startAt(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of Query.orderBy() clauses

with this code:

```
const query = firebase
  .getDatabase()
  .collection("users")
  .where("premium", "==", true) // get premium users
  .where("totalPosts", ">", 0); // that have posted some music


...

return query
    .startAt(0)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
          ...
    );
```

As you can see, I am trying to get premium users that have posted some music. I am using the where and startAt clause, and not the orderBy.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

> The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of Query.orderBy() clauses

Your code doesn't show any orderBy clauses at all, so the number in this case is 0.  But you provide 1 argument to `startAt()`.  You should actually provide an orderBy clause, to be specific.  It must match the field of your range query:

```
const query = firebase
  .getDatabase()
  .collection("users")
  .where("premium", "==", true) // get premium users
  .where("totalPosts", ">", 0)  // that have posted some music
  .orderBy("totalPosts")
```

Then, your pagination should repeat the exact same query, only this time with startAt to tell it where to pick up:

```
return query.startAt(0);
```

Comment: And why is necessary to use orderBy before startAt? Because of the totalPosts inequality or why? I mean, in a first moment I thought that with my first code I would be able to index myself in some document using startAt, but not the case.

Comment: A pagination query requires an understanding of the order of documents, so that the each page is using the same ordering for the same series of queries.  Firestore isn't going to guess the order you want.