# Too many arguments provided to startAt

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to search Firestore documents using StartAt() and EndAt() but I keep getting the error

> Too many arguments provided to startAt(). The number of arguments must
> be less than or equal to the number of orderBy() clauses.

I also have OrderBy included as indicated in this stackoverflow post -> [Firebase Error - Too many arguments provided to Query.startAt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199007/firebase-error-too-many-arguments-provided-to-query-startat)

The firestore query is being called as part of AutoCompleteTextView, not sure whats the issue here....

```
val mIndFilter = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
mIndFilter.collection("Industries").orderBy("industry").startAt(queryString).endAt(queryString + '\uf8ff').limit(5).get()
    .addOnCompleteListener {
       if(it.isSuccessful){
               allIndList = it.result.toObjects(Industries::class.java)
       }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.e("Ind Search Filter fail", "Error adding document $exception")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i literally ran into the same problem yesterday. here is how i solved it. hopefully it works for you too. use where clauses instead of startAt and endAt.

```
.collection("Industries")
    .orderBy("Industries", "asc")
    .where("Industries", ">=", queryString)
    .where("Industries", "<=", queryString + "\uf8ff")
    .limit(5)
    .get();
```